# About $\sigma$-algebras of Brownian Motion

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a standard brownian motion and $\tilde{B}_t = B_{t+s} - B_s$, for $t \geq 0$ and $s \geq 0$. And $\mathcal{F}^B$ = $(F_t^B)$ the natural filtration of $B$, where $F_t^B = \sigma(B_x: x \in [0,t])$. My question is, does
$$F_\infty^B = F_\infty^\tilde{B}? $$
I have shown that $\tilde{B}_t$ is independent of $F_s^B$. My intuition says yes, since both $B_t$ and $\tilde{B}_t$ are standard brownian motions, but i dont think it's simple as that.

Comment: Consider the event $A = \{B_s > 0\}$ which has probability $1/2$.  It is in $F^B_s$, hence in $F^B_\infty$, but not in $F^{\tilde{B}}_\infty$.

Comment: @NateEldredge How i can see that is not in $F_\infty^\tilde{B}$? $B_s = B_{t+s} - \tilde{B}_t$ but how i can prove it can't be expressed as a function only dependent of $\tilde{B}_t$

Comment: You showed that $F^B_s$ is independent of $\tilde{B}_t$ for every $t$, and an extension of that argument should show you that $F^B_s$ is independent of $F^{\tilde{B}}_\infty$.  So any event in $F^B_s \cap F^{\tilde{B}}_\infty$ is independent of itself and must therefore have probability 0 or 1.  But $A$ is in $F^B_s$ and has probability $1/2$, hence it cannot also be in $F^{\tilde{B}}_\infty$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thank you very much.